# Factor quadratic equation formula

Tags: quadratics

$ax^2+bx+c=(dx+e)(fx+g)$, and my goal is to find a formula to find $d,e,f,$ and $g$ when given $a,b,$ and $c$ and that also works for complex numbers

Comment: If you find the two roots of $ax^2+bx+c$, which we can say are $r_1$ and $r_2$, then $ax^2+bx+c=a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$. You can then manipulate $a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$ however you want to get the form you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality the standard quadratic factors as ...
$$ ax^2+bx+c=a(x-d)(x-e) $$

where $d$ and $e$ are the two solutions you get from the quadratic formula)

Answer (score -1):

By comparing the coefficients, we have
$$c=eg$$ 
$$a=df$$ 
$$b=dg+ef$$

There are three equations but four variables namely $d,e,f$ and $g$. So, you can not get a unique solution.